# Mongoose get chained result from one collection and pass it into another

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I have 2 collection in mongo as follows:

```
posts
    user_id
    description

activity
    user_id
    likes: [posts, posts, posts]
```

I would like to get all activities of a particular user. So I start by getting all the activities for the particular user then I would like to get all the posts for those activities as well so I try to chain it to `then` but the issue by the time, it gets to the second function... results becomes undefined. Is there a better way to do this with aggregate on mongo?

```
const query = { user_id: user_id}

Activity.findOne(query).lean()
    .then(function(results) {
        console.log(results)
        return results[0]; // returns the right result
    })
    .then(function(user) {
        console.log(user) // returns nulls
        return Posts.find({ user_id: user.user_id }).lean();
    })
    .then(function(results) {
        return results
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw(err)
    });
}
```

Comment: Instead of multiple `find` queries may be consider using a aggregation `$lookup` for a _join_ operation as a single query.

Comment: @prasad_ issue is that the likes is an array of posts so I need to see for each likes item... get the post details. I tried doing it that way but failed

Comment: Where is `repo` coming from: `console.log(repo)`?

Comment: @Jumshud whoops corrected it

Comment: Can you share the output of the `results` from the first invocation? If `results[0]` isn't null you should receive it in the next then callback